# Linux Kernel 3.x new versioning scheme

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

As almost everybody knows, Linux moved from the 2.6.x version to the brand new 3.x version.

I've seen around many comments also about the fact that the versioning number for the kernel was changed (wikipedia as the major source as you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Version_numbering) :) ).

The point is that, despite many information about changing the versioning scheme on a time-based format I wasn't able to find anywhere information related to the new versioning scheme.

Does anyone know how the new versioning scheme works?

Answer (score 6):

The new versioning scheme is pretty much exactly the same as the old 2.6 versioning scheme, except that "3." is used instead of "2.6."  In other words, instead of calling the release after 2.6.39 version 2.6.40, we just called it 3.0.  The stable updates, instead of 2.6.40.1, 2.6.40.2, etc. are now 3.0.1, 3.0.2, etc.  Instead of 2.6.41, we have 3.1.  And so on.

Nothing has changed about the development model, merge window, release cycle, etc.  The only change is that we have one fewer component to the version number (ie 3.x instead of 2.6.x).

Comment: And what about the last digit in the previous versioning system? example: 2.6.35.7 The last digit (related to bug fixes if I am not mistaken) is dropped? @Roland

Comment: No, the last digit was not dropped. We still have 3.0.1 ... 3.0.4 as "bugfix" releases for the 3.0 one.

Comment: I see... Since you are so kind last clarification :). Since 2.6 has now becomed 3.0 the minor revision number is no more used for discriminating among stable/development version (e.g. 2.5 development, 2.6 stable)? @Mircea

Comment: Right, but that it not a change with 3.0.  There are no more "development" or "unstable" releases of Linux; every release since 2.6.0 has been a "stable" release.

Comment: Wow, you are working on the kernel! I hope you find the time to write here a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Found some information in [this article](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2011/07/linux-kernel-version-bumped-up-to-30-as-20th-birthday-approaches.ars)

Mainly:

"The previous versioning scheme for the 2.6.x series emerged around 2005 from the kernel's transition to shorter time-based release cycles. The major and minor version numbers were pinned at 2.6 and the third digit was used to indicate the actual release. With the new model, the major version is pinned at 3 and the second digit will be used to indicate the actual release number and the third digit will be used for stable releases.

"This obviously also opens the merge window for the next kernel, which will be 3.1. The stable team will take the third digit, so 3.0.1 will be the first stable release based on 3.0," Torvalds explained in the release announcement."

Comment: I've seen that article but it does not provide good information about the new scheduling scheme. See the other reply + comments for further discussion

Comment: I read it as the 2.6 is removed in favor of 3, the other digits remain the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

If by "scheduling" you mean how development goes now, it is like this:

3.7 gets released (and the stable crowd starts their line of 3.7.1, 3.7.2, ...)
Linux opens the "merge window", around 2 weeks during which he will accept new features (which usually have been cooking elsewehere). When the merge window closes, Linus releases 3.8-rc0 (release candidate #0), after which *only* bug fixes are supposed to go into the kernel (sometimes a feature which was merged is taken back). Each following week (approximately) Linus releases -rc1, -rc2, ... until he is satisfied that there are no more bugs (typically around -rc6), and 3.8 is born. Then the cycle starts again. While all this goes on, the developer crowd is busy hacking on changes to be proposed for future merge windows (some features have been worked on literally for years before being deemed acceptable for inclusion).